# PHP Google API Client updating library problem

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-php-sdk

I have to update the `google/apiclient` package `1.0.*@dev` to `^2.2`.

I had this code in version 1.0:

```
$this->_client = new Google_Client();
$this->_client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    '__ACCOUNT__',
    ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"],
    file_get_contents('__PATH_TO_KEY__'))
);

$this->_client->setClientId('__CLIENT_ID__');
$this->_analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($this->_client);
```

How can I replace this code for version 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is from my sample project [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly");
$client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());

getOauth2Client()
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```